How much does "truth" matter in Tarski's undefinability of truth?
In many references (even quite scholastic ones),the authors present Tarski's theorem of undefinability of truth in a way that does not clarify what part of the concept of "truth" is needed in the result. This has given rise to a variety of meta-math and pseudo-math interpretations, which confuse. My question is what is the feature of the result that is closer to our  understanding of the countability of statements in a discrete language. This question I express more specifically below.
Assumptions. Consider the array $S(m,n)$ of all predicates of a single free variable $n$ (based on peano+logic), and sorted by Godel number $m$. Instead of "Truth", say there exists a mapping $B$ on $S(m,n)$ that is 0 or 1. We do not know this mapping, but say "Mary" know it (and can produce $B$ on any $S(m,n)$ by a push of button. Mary also observes that $B$ is not constant, and she notes down two specific statements in the array $S(m,n)$, say $S0$ and $S1$, for which she sees that $B$ is 0, and 1 respectively. Now, Mary defines a function $D(n)$ that, for each $n$, flips the outcome of $B$: $D(n) := S0$ if $B(S(n,n)) = 1$; and $S1$ if $B(S(n,n)) = 0$.
Observation: it seems to me, that, just like Tarski's result, $D(.)$ cannot by any of $S(m, .)$ because Mary constructed it to have the opposite $B$ characteristic-function than that of the diagonal of the array.
Question 1. Does that mean that $B(S(m,n))$ cannot be of the same  language (or nature) as $S(m,n)$ ?
Question 2. This would be much like the Turing's result for the halting problem, where if there were a machine $"B"$ that would determine, for any other machine $"S(m,n)"$ its halting behavior, it would allow creation of a new machine $D$ outside the list of machines. Yes ?
Question 3. But if yes, does it mean that, even for a computable by-us $B$ (say $B(S)$ tests if the string $S$ in arithmetic format is less than 100 characters long), the constructed $D(.)$ is external to the original array $S(m,.)$ ?
Thank you.
C Frangakis

This is not what I am asking. I am asking if the result stays the same when I replace "if there was a predicate of truth" (Tarski), by the assumption I have in my question.

Let me clarify the setup. Please correct me if I've misunderstood anything.
We fix a Gödel coding of definable predicates (first-order formulas in the language of arithmetic with a single free variables), and for simplicity we can assume that every natural number $n$ is the code of some definable predicate. Let's write $\varphi_n(x)$ for the predicate with code $n$.
Now Mary fixes a function $B\colon \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\to \{0,1\}$. The way you wrote your question, it looks like you intended $B$ to take sentences $\varphi(k)$ as input rather than codes. But any function $B'$ on sentences of this form induces a function $B$ on codes (by defining $B'(n,k) = B(\varphi_n(k))$, and if we want $B$ to be definable in the language of arithmetic, it has to take natural numbers as input, not sentences.
If $B$ is non-constant, Mary can pick $(n_0,k_0)$ and $(n_1,k_1)$ such that $B(n_0,k_0) = 0$ and $B(n_1,k_1) = 1$.
Now Mary defines $D(x)$ by $(B(x,x) = 0\rightarrow \varphi_{n_1}(k_1))\land (B(x,x) = 1\rightarrow \varphi_{n_0}(k_0))$.
Now if $B$ is not definable in the language of arithmetic, then there's no reason to expect that $D$ is a definable predicate. It manifestly has a different language/nature than the $\varphi_n(x)$, since its definition refers to the non-definable function $B$. So there's no paradox in this case.
Ok, so let's assume $B$ is a definable function. Then $D(x)$ is a definable predicate, so it has some code, say $n^*$.
What is $\varphi_{n^*}(n^*)$? Well, it is $D(n^*)$, which is $(B(n^*,n^*) = 0\rightarrow \varphi_{n_1}(k_1))\land (B(n^*,n^*) = 1\rightarrow \varphi_{n_0}(k_0))$.
We have:

If $B(n^*,n^*) = 0$, then $\varphi_{n^*}(n^*)$ is equivalent to $\varphi_{n_1}(k_1)$, and $B(n_1,k_1) = 1$.
If $B(n^*,n^*) = 1$, then $\varphi_{n^*}(n^*)$ is equivalent to $\varphi_{n_0}(k_0)$, and $B(n_0,k_0) = 0$.

But there's no contradiction here! There's no reason to expect that the function $B$ carries equivalent inputs to equal outputs. For example, in your question you considered the function $B(x,y)$ which tests if the string $\varphi_x(y)$ is less than $100$ characters long. Letting $a$ be the code for $x = x$, and letting $b$ be the code for $\bigwedge_{i=1}^{100} x = x$, we have $B(a,0) = 1$ and $B(b,0) = 0$, even though these two formulas are equivalent.
On the other hand, by introducing an extra assumption, we can turn this failed paradox into a theorem (which is a proper generalization of Tarski's theorem). Let's say a function $B\colon \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\to \{0,1\}$ is equivalence-invariant if for all $x,y,x',y'\in \mathbb{N}$, if $\varphi_x(y)$ is equivalent to $\varphi_{x'}(y')$, then $B(x,y) = B(x',y')$. Then the construction above gives a contradiction, and we have proved:
Theorem: Every definable equivalence-invariant function $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\to \{0,1\}$ is constant.
The moral is that while there are many definable functions on codes, we shouldn't expect them to be able to unpack the codes and do any non-trivial reasoning about the meaning of the coded formulas. Tarski's undefinability of truth is one manifestation of this informal idea, and the theorem above is another one.

Thanks. I understand what you write: if a property B depends on S only through its Truth-equivalence characteristic function, then B is undefinable in the language of S (unless constant), because (1) we construct D to contradict at the level of different B-characteristic functions, yet (2) we say we draw meaning at the level of Truth-characteristic functions. But this holds true for any "Truth-characteristic function".  In other words, the same result holds if "truth" is not TRUTH, but any array T[m,n] attached to S[m,n], and on which we ask B[m,n] to respect it.  Correct ?

It is this that my questions is going after. What is the non-meaningful structure (void of philosophical meaning) that we use to model the meaningful narrative part of the above result, so that we can see what are the basics (what axioms or lack, in Peano) that prevent definition of such Bs.

@ConstantineFrangakis Yes, I think your understanding is correct. As for your second comment, I'm afraid I don't understand what you're after well-enough to say anything useful.

Here e is what I mean: Tarski's undefinability, using proof by contradiction, does not clarify if the reason is the countable restrictions of finite language, or that even for single specific $S(m,n)$ statements, Truth is undefinable. It seems to me that for every specific S, when godel-unpacked, is a finite string of the allowed symbols of peano+logic. This will be at most a specific combination of countably infinite unions and interactions of finite checks.

So imagine an idealized program (not universal machine) built specifically to check the countably infinite series. For example, for Goldbach's we can say Intersection_{even j=2 to inf} check{j}, where check{j} has the finite checks.  A idealized machine that checks j=1,.... N, N-> infinity, defines the truth o Goldbachs. I think this can be done for every well formed formula S. If that is true, then it means that the problem is not at the specific level of any S[m,n], but at the "putting together of the countably infinities [m,n] of the specific cases.

I have a clarification to ask on your answer, after you write "Ok, so let's assume  is a definable function.". Mary had created a (D_(x))  EQUAL to  (\phi_{n_1}(k_1)) or  (\phi_{n_0}(k_0)) if (B(x,x)) is 0/1 inversely respectively.  Since, when we say equal we mean equal (in godel number), does this not mean that there is no (n^) for which (\phi_{n^}(x) EQUALS (D(x)) for all x,  because at (x=n^*) we DO NOT get equality, we just get equivalence ?

It's not possible to write down a $D(x)$ which is EQUAL to one sentence or another depending on the value of $x$. Remember, a definable predicate is an actual string of symbols. If $D(x)$ depends on the value of $x$, the free variable $x$ must appear in it somewhere, but neither $\varphi_{n_0}(k_0)$ nor $\varphi_{n_1}(k_1)$ has any free variables. @ConstantineFrangakis

D(x) = phi(n0,k0) if B[n0,k0]=1 and phi(n1,k1) if B[n1,k1]=0

I think you defined that the same way in your main answer. This is a string. Then D(x) we say must be some phi(n*, x).Does this not mean then that D(x) = phi(n*, x) for every x, but that the have different B() for every x ? Sorry if I am not getting something, but I am trying.  My main problem is that it looks to me that, if even if B is well defined predicate (say length of string <100), we can define a D(x) whose B-values over x are the opposite of the B values of the diagonal.

Is that a typo? To feed into the "paradox", $D(x)$ has to pick one of the $\varphi$s based on the value of $B(x,x)$, not $B(n_0,k_0)$ and $B(n_1,k_1)$.

I understand the equivalent issue (that different phis can have different Bs even if the phis have the same meaning).  But that's not my issue. My issue is: that D(x) has a B-dignature outside anyone in { phi{n,x} }, means D(x) is different from any. But why is it different ? D(x) is well defined with something like 35 characters (not in actual Peano but ok) So, it is one of 26^35  possible strings for that many characters. Why is it not there ? (regardless of equivalence with others, it must be there, right ?)

I'm really not sure what the confusion is here. Yes, $D(x)$ appears on our list, with Gödel number $n^$. But your construction does not imply that the $B$-signature of $D(x)$ disagrees with the $B$-signature of $\varphi_{n_}$. You seem to think Mary can define $D(x)$ so that it has Gödel number $n_0$ sometimes and Gödel number $n_1$ other times. This is nonsense: $D(x)$ has a fixed Gödel number, $n^*$, which is not equal to $n_0$ or $n_1$.

Your comment helped me a lot. My remaining issue is on the specific conditions that can create contradiction. Contradiction will arise generally if B is kind of distributive:  B( S0 if C1  or S0 if ~C1) = B(S0) if C1 or B(S0) if ~B(C1);  where C1=B(S(n*,n*)).  Then, we will have contradiction. And yes, B that satisfies that cannot be any property. It definitely is any property acting on S through its truth value (equivalence). But is there any other B that can satisfy the above and hence be NOT definable from the same language (by contradiction) ?

(sorry I am correcting a typo):

B( S0 if C1 or S1 if ~C1) = B(S0) if C1 or B(S1) if ~B(C1); where C1=B(S(n*,n*)).

I think the comment thread has gone on long enough, so this is my last comment here. I can't think of any natural condition on $B$, other than equivalence-invariance, that would imply the condition in your last comment.

This is a different question, but related to the connection between Logic and Statistical Evidence.  So, you can say if you want it posted. I think I have found a result that I have never see elsewhere, and would like to ask confirmation.  The context can be simple: an experiment is conducted, and we can observe x=1,... with  either distribution a(.) or distribution b(.). Statistics has been interested in defining an Evidence function that knows a(.) and b(.), observes x, and produces output that is intended to mean the evidence for a vs b based on x. Standard statistics ...

consider axioms of sufficiency  and conditionality (not always so), and find that evidence is a function of the ration a(x)/b(x). However, not everyone fins those axioms apparent. I propose instead, that if evidence means a distillation of everything we can say about a vs b based on x, the we can capture that by saying that Ev introspects on its own product (self reference), it should give back the same result: Ev (Ev()) should be Ev. Based on such assumption on the comparison of a(x) and b(x), I show that there's is only one such non trivial function Ev and it is the Ratio a(x)/b(x).
